# citing reference

Tags: cross-referencing

when I cited reference in theorem environment, the complied result is of the form

Lemma 4.1. *[ 10, Lemma 5.1.]* A is of full rank.

Namely, the font is oblique.
 But I want the form of

Lemma 4.1. [ 10, Lemma 5.1.] A is of full rank.

Can you help me?

Following is the LaTeX code.

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,reqno]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm,mathrsfs,mathtools,array,booktabs,caption2}
\usepackage{dcolumn,natbib}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[section]
\newtheorem{coro}{Corollary}[section]
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\DeclareFixedFont{\myfont}{T1}{pzc}{mb}{it}{22pt}
\begin{document}

\begin{lemma} \cite[Lemma 5.1]{zhang2015perturbation}
A is of full rank.

\end{lemma}

\bibliographystyle{plain}

\begin{thebibliography}{1}

\bibitem{zhang2015perturbation}

{Y.~Zhang, L.~Zhang, J.~Wu, and J.~Zhang},
\newblock {\em A perturbation approach for an inverse quadratic programming problem
  over second-order cones},
\newblock Math. Comput. 84(2015), pp. 209--236.

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because the reference comes in the body where the font is italic. Use

```
{\normalfont\cite[Lemma 5.1]{zhang2015perturbation}}
```

to cite there. Note the surrounding braces here that limit the scope of `\normalfont`.

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,reqno]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm,mathrsfs,mathtools,array,booktabs,caption2}
\usepackage{dcolumn,natbib}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[section]
\newtheorem{coro}{Corollary}[section]
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\DeclareFixedFont{\myfont}{T1}{pzc}{mb}{it}{22pt}
\begin{document}

\begin{lemma} {\normalfont\cite[Lemma 5.1]{zhang2015perturbation}}
A is of full rank.

\end{lemma}

\bibliographystyle{plain}

\begin{thebibliography}{1}

\bibitem{zhang2015perturbation}

{Y.~Zhang, L.~Zhang, J.~Wu, and J.~Zhang},
\newblock {\em A perturbation approach for an inverse quadratic programming problem
  over second-order cones},
\newblock Math. Comput. 84(2015), pp. 209--236.

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @zqj You are welcome. Thank you for accepting the answer. Have a nice time TeXing. :-)